# Application structure for Node project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, reactjs, flux

I have two separate applications calling more or less same API functions. One application is built using Angular and the other application using React + Flux. Both the applications have to interact with the same database.

My angular application adds new data to the database and my react app uses that data to do some other stuff. I want to know if I can build the structure shown in the image below.

So, my applications should communicate with the same server hosting `API functions` and should share a common database. Using this, I can avoid duplicating same server side logic on two different projects.

[image: Application structure to implement]

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible.

The open question is how the React App gets notified if the angular app changes something. Possible technologies for this are sockets or polling.

Another possibillity is to let the Angular App directly ping the React App.

Comment: Yeah true I need to keep that in mind. I am not sure how to implement the wireframe considering that I need to make the react app as isomorphic/universal. Just trying to find out that how the whole application will be structured.

Comment: To summarize your system: You have a AngularJs App accessed via a browser, a bundeld React App accessed as App from a desktop or a mobile and somwhere do you have a server with NodeJS and a Database. Than the image you posted is a sensible structure.